# ASP.NET MVC & WEB API autenticação com token

Tags: asp.net, oauth2

Tenho uma dúvida sobre o bearer token. Eu tenho dois cenários na minha aplicação. 1º é um painel admin que trabalha com ASP.NET MVC e angularjs e o 2º é o WEB Api que troca requisições com um aplicativo WPF. Minha dúvida é sobre o token, se é indiferente eu utilizá-lo para um controller ASP.NET MVC e um controller Web api.

```
 public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();            
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        try
        {
            DbEngine db = new DbEngine();
            var user = db.AutenticacaoAPI(context.UserName, context.Password);
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            if (user.Status)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Value.ST_NOME));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Value.ST_LOGIN));
            }

            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        catch
        {
            context.SetError("Usuário e senha inválidos", "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

e o código do Controller para requisitar as informações do usuário somente para testar o serviço

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult UserInfo(string login)
    {
        using (DbEngine db = new DbEngine())
        {
            try
            {
                return new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = db.GetUser(login),
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ReturnException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
```

Aqui é o retorno do token

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui a chamada que me devolve este erro mesmo com o token no header

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema não é com o `ASP.NET Identity` ou com o `ASP.NET MVC`, mas sim ao tentar serializar o proxy da Entity `Usuario`.

Este Proxy é criado para que seja possível realizar o `LazyLoad` nas consultas, então tente desativar o LazyLoad e passe à utilizar o `.Include())` sempre que necessário.

Comment: Obrigada, vou tentar desativar para ver se funciona. Agradeço sua ajuda

Comment: Eu desativei o Lazy Load mas continuou o mesmo problema, então pesquisei mais um pouco e achei a solução nesse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588143/ef-4-1-code-first-json-circular-reference-serialization-error aí eu só inseri `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` e consegui fazer o get. Vou marcar como a resposta certa porque você me deu a direção correta para solucionar meu problema, agradeço sua ajuda.